# Apply transtition animation on control

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

There's transition animation in page navigation. But I want to apply it on `SemanticView`.

I have a list of list of object, on the pivot, it will display a list of 
list first. When user want to view the detailed information about the list, the user will tap it, and the list of list will removed, and display the list of object. Tap hardware back button will bring out the list of list again.

Without confusing the user, I want to display transition animation when user tap the list or the hardware back button, it will have `ForwardIn`, `ForwardOut`, `BackwardIn`, `BackwardOut` animation when the list changed. How do I display transition animation on the `SemanticView` without nagivating to other page?

Answer (score 1):

well, inever tried this but you probably had to create a class with extend to animation class something like

```
public class Animation : AnimationWindowsPhoneClass
{
   implement the animation.
}
```

or.. you can create your own animation using Storyboard class, you can read [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.storyboard)